# libpq - PQsendQuery wait for complete result

Tags: c, postgresql, asynchronous, libpq

I'm having problem with libpq's `PQexec` function hanging on intermittent
connections. After looking around the mailing list, the solution is to use the
asynchronous functions `PQsendQuery`/`PQgetResult` and implement your own timeout.

Now the
issue I'm facing is that `PQgetResult` needs to be called multiple times until
it returns `null` and then you know it's done. However, the rest of my
application expects a single `PQresult` object per query.

So my question is:

1. Is there a way to concatenate/join the multiple `PQresult`s?
2. Can I somehow use `PQisBusy` & `PQconsumeInput` to wait until all the
   results are ready before calling `PQgetResult`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**credits** to Laurenz Albe to who [answered](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/libpq-PQsendQuery-wait-for-complete-result-td5734111.html#a5734321) this over on the postgresql mailing list.

If you have a single SQL statement, you will get only one 
`PQresult`.  You get more than one if you send a query string 
with more than one statement, e.g.

```
PQsendQuery(conn, "SELECT 42; SELECT 'Hello'");
```

would result in two `PQresults`.

You can get multiple `PQresults` only using asynchronous 
command processing; the corresponding PQexec would return 
only the PQresult of the *last* statement executed.

So you can get the same behaviour as `PQexec` by discarding 
all `PQresults` except for the last one.